# mbuild not working

Tags: matlab

I am using R2008b version of matlab and trying to run 'mbuild -setup' but it comes up with an error:
??? Undefined function or method 'mbuild' for input arguments of type 'char'.

I've looked in the install directory and there is nothing called mbuild, the path with matlab seems to be pointing to alot of toolboxes so I added in the bin and bin\win64 directories but still nothing.  my environment variable PATH is also pointing to win64.
Anybody have any suggestions on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the MATLAB Compiler toolbox. It does not come with the basic matlab installation..

Comment: great thanks.  is this the same as the MCR? I checked the path and there doesnt seem to be a compiler toolbox.  where can i find this?  the mathworks site only has downloads for 2012 version

Comment: you can type 'ver' in matlab. It lists all available toolboxes. You have pay extra to have it in your license. Then you can choose to install it during the installation process.